# Tower-of-squares sequence divides linear recurrent A001921 sequence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

Let $(a_n)$ be the [A001921](http://oeis.org/A001921) sequence

$$
  a_0 = 0,\ a_1 = 7, \quad a_{n+2} = 14a_{n+1} - a_n + 6.
$$

Let $(b_k)$ be the (almost)"tower-of-squares" sequence defined by

$$
  b_0=2, \quad b_{k+1}=2b_k^2-1
$$

Is it true that $a_{2^kn+2^{k-1}-1}$ is always divisible by
  $b_k$, for any $k,n\geq 0$ ?

I have checked this up to $k=6$. For example :

- $a_{2n}$ is always divisible by $b_0=2$.
- $a_{4n+1}$ is always divisible by $b_1=7$.
- $a_{8n+3}$ is always divisible by $b_2=97$.
- Etc. Up to : $a_{128n+65}$ is always divisible by $b_6=2011930833870518011412817828051050497$.

  This is a cross-post from a MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002792/does-the-a001921-linear-recurrent-integer-sequence-always-yield-composite-number).

Comment: Does any enlightenment occur when you write the a-recurrence in matrix form?  Gerhard "Or Maybe Tilt Your Head" Paseman, 2014.11.06

Comment: @GerhardPaseman When I write $X_n=(1,a_n,a_{n+1})$ and $X_{n+1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 &  1 \\ 6 & -1 & 14 \end{array}\right)X_n$, no flash occurs in my brain. But maybe I am being blind on this one …

Comment: OK.  I was thinking 2x2 matrices with a' = (6 0) + Aa, and then calling this operation Va and trying V iterated to a high power.  I haven't followed it up though.  Gerhard "Maybe Smaller Will Be Better" Paseman, 2014.11.06

Comment: @GerhardPaseman The closed-form formula for $a_n$ is of the form $-\frac{1}{2}+c(7- 4\sqrt{3})^n+d(7+ 4\sqrt{3})^n$. Not very helpful for integer divisibility properties it seems

Comment: Some thoughts that can be helpful:  1) you perhaps prefer to consider the sequence $d_n=2a_n+1$, as it satisfies a homogeneous linear recurrence $d_{n+1}=14d_n-d_{n-1}$  -- and prove the congruence to 1 modulo the sequence $c_n=2b_n$ ;   2) for the latter, the recurrence relation is also simplified: $c_{n+1}=c_n^2-2$.   3) It would be natural to expect that $A^{2^n}=id$ mod $c_n$, where $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 14 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) $ is the corresponding transition matrix.

Comment: @VictorKleptsyn Looks very helpful indeed! I'll work on that.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I'm not sure this will be needed, but just in case: $7+4\sqrt{3}= (2+\sqrt{3})^2$. Thus the matrix A is a square, but of a matrix with rational elements (there will be 1/4 and 15/4).

Comment: @PietroMajer Sorry, but I get +1: the fixed constant of the recurrence is $(-1/2)$:
$$-\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{14}{2} -(-\frac{1}{2}) +6$$

Comment: sorry, now I see!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The elements of your sequence are
$$a_n=\left(\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}}{2}\right)$$
where $\alpha=2+\sqrt{3}$ and $\beta=2-\sqrt{3}$. Notice that both factors are integers. We can also compute that
$$b_n=\frac{\alpha^{2^n}+\beta^{2^n}}{2}.$$
Now your statement that $b_k$ always divides $a_{2^{k+1}n+2^k-1}$ follows from the fact that
$\frac{\alpha^{2^k}+\beta^{2^k}}{2}$ divides $\frac{\alpha^{2^k(2n+1)}+\beta^{2^k(2n+1)}}{2}$, which is very easy to check (the ratio is a polynomial in $\alpha, \beta$ and symmetric in both).

Comment: Very nice. May I ask how you discovered the factorization of $a_n$ ? Did you use some sort of systematic method ?

Comment: I think I see already : the initial recurrence has eigenvalues that happen to be fourth powers. So, one looks for factor sequences that satisfy a reccurence whose eigenvalues are the fourth roots of the initial roots.

Comment: By the factorization a_n is composite, except for finite exceptions?

Comment: @joro: indeed both factors diverge, and satisfy a linear recurrence

Comment: @PietroMajer Indeed. so a_n is the product of two lower order recurrences.