# Transforming a recurrence to the product of two other recurrences

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences

This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186390/tower-of-squares-sequence-divides-linear-recurrent-a001921-sequence) deals with sequence:

$$a_0 = 0,\ a_1 = 7, \quad a_{n+2} = 14a_{n+1} - a_n + 6$$

The question is about establishing that $a_n$ is a composite number (except some finite cases).

In one of the comments to @Gjergji Zaimi's answer, @joro said:

> So $a_n$ is the product of two lower order recurrences.

I am not clear on how this conclusion is reached. Also, I would like to see some recurrent formula in different form than original, that illustrates this.

This is interesting to me since I work on some other problems involving primality, and understanding this approach may greately help me.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just consider Gjergji Zaimi's formula: each factor is a linear combination of $n$-th powers of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which are roots of $x^2-4x+1$. So both factors satisfy the same linear recurrence, $f_{n+2}-4f_{n+1}+f_n=0$, just as $\alpha^n$ and $\beta^n$ do.

Comment: $a_2$ is even. So all next $a_n$ for $n\ge 2$ are even too and so composite.

Comment: @PietroMajer, the quoted statement is that the sequence is a product of two *lower order* recurrences. I interpret this as both factors satisfying a first order recurrence relation. Or does lower order mean something else here?

Comment: I think expression "lower order" is confusing, I will delete it from the title. @JoonasIlmavirta

Comment: Linear recurrences with constant coefficients are closed under multiplication. In general this increases the order.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta They satisfy _second_ order recurrences, since the constant coefficient in the OP increases the order to $3$.

Comment: @joro: the order of a non-homogeneous recurrence is usual defined as the same of the homogeneous part. Why increasing it?

Comment: @PietroMajer OK, might be wrong. I meant if one homogenize it, the order in general increases.

Comment: (@Sergei: actually $a_{n+2}=a_n\mod2$ so $a_n=n \mod2$)

Answer (score 3):

From Gjergji Zaimi's answer:

$$ a_n=\left(\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}}{2}\right)$$.

Both factors are integers and satisfy binary recurrences.

Experimentally the first is https://oeis.org/A001353 and the second is https://oeis.org/A001075.

Numerical data supports this.

Comment: Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are....?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In the answer in the linked question: $\alpha=2+\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Much better, I think, if symbols are explained in situ, rather than by going somewhere else on the page and then to some other page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, agree with you. This was written in a hurry and currently don't feel like popping the question to the front page...

Answer (score 1):

Look, I want to use the most standard approach: we have 
$$
X_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+2}
\\
a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
14&-1
\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1}
\\
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
6
\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=\mathcal A X_n + b,\quad X_0=\begin{pmatrix}
7
\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The matrix $\mathcal A$ is invertible and $b=\begin{pmatrix}
6
\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$. We have thus with an arbitrary vector $c\in \mathbb R^2$,
$$
X_{n+1}+c=\mathcal A \bigl(X_n + \mathcal A^{-1}(b+c)\bigr),
$$
and we may choose that $c$ such that
$
c=\mathcal A^{-1}(b+c),
$
i.e.
$
(\mathcal A-I)c= b
$
which is (uniquely) possible since $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $\mathcal A$.
With $Y_n=X_n+c$, we have thus
$$
Y_{n+1}=\mathcal A Y_n\Longrightarrow Y_{n}=\mathcal A^n Y_0.
$$
The eigenvalues of $\mathcal A$ are (real and) distinct, so we have with a diagonal 
$\mathcal D$ 
$$
\mathcal A=P\mathcal D P^{-1}\Longrightarrow\mathcal A^n=P\mathcal D^n P^{-1},
$$
making everything completely explicit.